# findVIewById(R.id.My_id) returns null. setContentView(R.layout.my_custom_layout) works, but how to return?

Tags: java, android

Making small data organizer.
Upon clicking on item appears custom dialog, for which i've created custom xml.
The xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.8"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Edit Item"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/item_edit_entity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Entity"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="6dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/Item_edit_value"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Value"
                android:maxLength="30" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

So, its custom xml, it works. I started to add functionality, and face a problem.

```
  private final static String FILE_NAME = "content.txt";
    public void okClicked() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item Saved!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {

            @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast") EditText textBox = findViewById(R.id.item_edit_entity);
            @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast") EditText textBox2 = findViewById(R.id.Item_edit_value);
            String text = textBox.getText().toString();
            String text2 = textBox2.getText().toString();
            String text3=text2+"||"+text;
            fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(text3.getBytes());
            Toast.makeText(this, "File Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        catch(IOException ex) {

            Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        finally{
            try{
                if(fos!=null)
                    fos.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ex){

                Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


    }
```

This code supposed to take text from EditText positions, each of them have a id.
But findViewById returns null. In general that is the main issue need to be solved. :)

Oh, i've read a lot of stackoverflow articles, and searched the internet.

I've tried to use `setContentView(R.layout.my_custom_xml)` and it worked.
But then another problem appears - after things done the screen becomes as in layout my_custom_xml.
Trying to switch back on `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` leads to empty screen beacuse all the content is added via code and not in the xml file.

So, questions: how to access R.id.my_Custom_id_in_custom_xml from code? Possible without switching by `setContentView`. If is the main an the right solution, then how to restore window stance as it was before clicking. Or how to rebuild (call?) the main screen if other options is impossible. Can i just call the `onCreate`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might be calling the wrong View

just replace `<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText`
with `<EditText`.

Or in you class file replace `EditText` with `TextInputEditText`, and it will solve your issue.

the error is occurring because you are implementing the `TextInputEditText` but calling it as `EditText`.

Happy coding ✌️

Comment: It works fine if i change view with setContentView function.

Comment: when are you trying the show this custom layout, like on any click or event.